# Android add my onw ssl certificate

Tags: android, ssl, https, request, certificate

I have create my ssl for my glassfish server to use https.But when try to make https request with (retrofit or volley)get back Exception:The server certificate wasn't signed by a CA, but was self signed.
The question :Need i install my ssl on android device or create trustManager?

Comment: You can create your own `TrustManager[]` that includes your self-signed certificate. I have some code for that in [my CWAC-Security library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/TrustManagerBuilder.markdown).

Comment: Why don't you generate a trusted certificate from a CA? With a self signed it's almost impossible to deal properly with the revocation